# Dijkstra's algorithm - additional properties

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Say we let $R$ denote the set of currently chosen vertices in Dijkstra's algorithm, $d$ be the currently stored path-length estimates, and $s$ be the source. The standard property that we know is true is that for all $r\in R$, $d(r)$ is the correct shortest path length from $s$ to $r$.

I was just wondering if the following additional properties would be true:

- For all $r\in R$, the shortest path from $s$ to $r$ lies completely within $R$.
- For all $u\not\in R$, $d(u)$ is the length of the shortest path from $s$ to $u$ which passes through only vertices in $R$ (except $u$ itself, of course).

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried searching for counterexamples?  Have you tried proving it?  What progress have you made?  We prefer that you ask only one question per post.

Comment: Try proving these claims inductively (the induction is on the number of steps in the algorithm). If you succeed, you will have proved the claims. If you fail, try to use this failure to construct a counterexample.